# Checking balanced characters doesn't work

Tags: linux, perl, text

I want to write a perl script for checking if some characters are balanced in a string or not. if they are not balance, it would remove them.
for example if a string only contains open parenthesis, this characters have to be removed. I used the following code, but it doesn't work...

```
sub checkBalance{
    my $text= $_[0];
    ### Check Balanced Quates
    my $count = ($text =~ tr/"//);
    if ( $count%2 !=0)
    {
      $text=~ s/"//g;
    }
    ### Check Balanced «»
    if (((($text =~ m#(.*».*)#) && !($text =~ m#(.*«.*)#)) || !(($text =~ m#(.*».*)#) && ($text =~ m#(.*«.*)#))) || (index($text, "«")>index($text, "»")))
    {
      $text=~ s/»//g;
      $text=~ s/«//g;
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Why it doesn't work?

The pl file is UTF8. Sample input is:

```
 می گوید: «یکی از اصول
```

and expected output is:

```
 می گوید: یکی از اصول
```

I used this code on an English string, it seems that it works for English strings, but not other languages such as Arabic and  Persian.

Comment: How does it not work? Provide sample input and the corresponding expected output. What encoding did you use, and how did you communicate that to Perl if you used something other than iso-8859-1?

Comment: I use this code for processing UTF8 encoded files.

Comment: I meant what encoding did you use for the source file. Let me clarify:

Comment: How does it not work? Provide sample input and the corresponding expected output. What encoding did you use for the source file, and how did you communicate that to Perl if you used something other than iso-8859-1? What encoding did you use for the source file, and how did you communicate that to Perl?

Comment: Now please answer the rest! Your answer is *completely* useless on its own.

Comment: My text files are UTF8, I wrote a perl script for reading UTF8 input files, split lines in to sentences and then check sentences for balanced characters.

Comment: You already said that. Is something I asked unclear?

Comment: I used this code for opening input files: open(my INFILE, "<:utf8", "$InputFile") || die "Can't open input  file: '$InputFile': $!";

Comment: Are these descriptions enough?

Comment: What's the expected output? (From what I see, your function removes the "«" and nothing else.) What encoding did you use for the source file (the .pl file)?

Comment: (A shorter example would have been better since it's hard for me to see the quotes in there.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13326/discussion-between-hakim-and-ikegami)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the missing bits:

```
use utf8;                               # Tell Perl script is encoded using UTF-8.
use strict;
use warnings;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';    # Tell Perl terminal expects UTF-8.
use feature qw( say );

sub checkBalance{
   ...
}

my $in = " می گوید: «یکی از اصول";
my $expect = " می گوید: یکی از اصول";
my $got = checkBalance($in);

say $in;
say $expect;
say $got;
say $got eq $expect ? "Got expected output" : "Didn't get expected output.";
```

I get the correct output:

```
$ perl x.pl
 می گوید: «یکی از اصول
 می گوید: یکی از اصول
 می گوید: یکی از اصول
Got expected output
```

I suspect you didn't tell Perl your source file is encoded using UTF-8. Add `use utf8;`.

In the future, please provide a demonstration of problem. Simply posting your function does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you dear ikegami, my bad mistake was that I hadn't used (use utf8;) in my code. By adding this line, the code works fine...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to roll your own, there is a [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aBalanced) to handle the problems of finding balanced delimiters in text.